# Charge 12 V, 1.3 Ah lead acid battery via 12 V, 5 watt solar panel

Tags: batteries, mosfet, solar-cell, panel

Can someone explain me the below circuit which is used to charge 12 V 1.3 Ah lead acid battery via 12 V, 5 watt solar panel?

The circuit is shown below I need to know what is happening in this specific circuit.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a device to prevent the solar panel charging the battery. It won't do that because of the body diode. Where did you find it?

Comment: u mean the diode D52, i think that is for preventing  the battery from discharging

Comment: No I do not. but you are correct about D52 function. As I asked, where did you find this circuit? (I have my own guess)

Comment: Those resistor ratios put the inputs to the LM358 above its input common mode range, they go to the negative rail, but stop 1.7 V below the positive one.

Comment: No, he means the diode in Q3 so the mosfet will never close.

Comment: can you explain me how the mosfet will never close

Comment: Because the body diode in Q3 will be forward biassed when the opamp switches Q3 off.

Comment: Where did you get this schematics, selfmade one? The Q3, P-channel will not work as expected. Try to exchange Source with Drain of the Q3.....

Comment: what i understood from the schematic is that the lm358 will compare the voltages across the battery and the solar panel. the vcc given to the lm358 is 5v. so if the voltage across the solar panel which is connected to the non inverting input of the lm358  is greater than  the voltage across the battery which is connected to the inverting input , the opampl output will saturate towards the positve rail and switch ON the mosfet allowing the current to charge the battery. someone tell if i right or wrong

Comment: First, the opamp will never work because both inputs are outside (0,VCC) if VCC = 5V, so it needs to be 12V. Second, if the opamp output saturates to +12V, the same as Q3 Source voltage, that turns q3 OFF, preventing charging. Third, when the solar cell is sufficiently higher than the battery, the body diode in Q3 is forward biassed so it conducts despite the FET being off. Tom Kuschel is right : reverse the FET. Then rewire the opamp inputs so that its output is 0 (not 12V) when you want Q3 ON. Also run teh opamp off Vbat. And increase R7,R14 to at least 10kilohms per Neil UK's comment.

Comment: It won't work with  Vcc = 5V. It won't work with the FET the way it is connected. It won't work the way the op amp inputs are connected. Your description of the intended operation sounds correct, but it is useless because diode D52 already performs the same function. You need a circuit that _regulates_ the battery voltage.

Comment: And furthermore, you can't charge a 12V lead-acid battery from a 12V source using any kind of linear regulator. You need a significantly higher input voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume

Solar panel generates a voltage **Vs**,

Op-amp U4:A has a gain of **A**,

Then,

Equation for op-amp U4:A is given by:

$$V_{out} = A(V_{+} - V_{-})$$
$$V_{out} = A\bigg(V_{s}\bigg(\dfrac{R10}{R10+R7}\bigg)+V_{chrg+}\bigg(\dfrac{R15}{R15+R14}\bigg)\bigg)$$

$$V_{out} = A(V_{s}(0.909) - V_{chrg+}(0.909))$$
$$V_{out} = A(0.909)(V_{s} - V_{chrg+})$$

Hence from the above equation one can see when Vs > Vchrg+ then Vout is high (Vcc) and when Vchrg+ < Vs then Vout is low (GND).

Also Q3 is a PMOS so the ON condition for PMOS is

$$V_{sd} > V_{sg} – |V_{t}| $$

i.e.

$$(V_{s}-V_{chrg+}) > (V_{s} - V_{out}) – |V_{t}| $$

(Vt's value can be determined from the datasheet of PMOS Q3)

**Therefore if you solve it further, simply put, the charging will start (i.e. Q3 will turn ON) only when the solar panel voltage is more than the battery's voltage by some threshold**

This is because if let say Q3 turns ON and battery's voltage is less than solar panel's generated voltage, the current will flow from battery to the solar panel which is undesirable. However diode D52 is there to prevent that (to provide extra protection, in case PMOS is shorted due to over current, then with no diode in place the current will flow from battery to solar panel)

Comment: So what I hear you saying is that the MOSFET and op amp are completely redundant...D52 prevents reverse current all by itself. Won't the MOSFET's body diode conduct regardless of the voltage provided by the op amp?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson No i'm not saying that. What i'm saying is that let there be a circuit without the diode, and due to an over-current the MOSFET is damaged (D-S short). The diode is acting as an extra protection for the circuit.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson And about the body diode. **NO!**, body diode does not work this way, it represents the parasitic behavior b/w the channel and the substrate. This is a vast topic itself. Please read about body diode, reverse recovery time in switching applications etc....